# Given date launched (y/m/d) and deadline (y/m/d) columns, how do I write duration command on SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m very new to SQL, so sorry for the noob question.

I was given a table to analyse and I want to find the days passed between all the dates launched and dates of the deadline in a new column I made called duration. Then I want to find the average of those days. What would be the command I write for that?

——————————————

Launched | Deadline | Duration|

——————————————-

Avg | Avg | Avg

That’s what I want to do/find. I don’t know how to start/write it.

Comment: So there is a deadline and an actually launch date which can be before or after the deadline? You, however don't wan't to know how often a deadline was met or not met, you merely want to know the avarage number of days between the two? So with two projects (?) finished a week in advance and one two weeks late, you'd want to show the number zero?

Comment: Please have a look at the below answer - does that work for you?

Comment: I think you need to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You shouldn't store redundant data in a table, by the way. What you call duration seems to be just the difference between the two dates. You can always retrieve this from the existing columns.

Comment: There’s a launch date column and a deadline column with hundreds of dates. The projects end by the deadline, whether or not it was complete or not. I made a new column and I want to find the days passed for each project row. Is that doable?

Comment: The specification would be much more clearly illustrated with *sample data* and an *example* of the expected output.

Comment: So each project ends at `launched` which is never greater than `deadline`. But a "duration" would be from some *start date* till the launch date, not the difference between `launched` and `deadline`. And as mentioned, don't store values you can calculate from existing values. Redundance can easily lead to inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use datediff

```
select datelaunched, deadline, datediff(day, datelaunched, deadline)
union all
select avg(datelaunched), avg(deadline), avg(datediff(day, datelaunched, deadline))
```

Comment: I sort of understand the answer.  But an upvote on an answer that is syntactically incorrect for MySQL is curious.

Comment: I'm curious about taking an "average" of a DATE value... casting date to numeric YYYYMMDD, taking an average of the numeric value, and  returning a decimal value that is potentially not a valid date? Why? (And DATEDIFF function takes two arguments, were we intending to use TIMESTAMPDIFF?)

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you want something like this:

```
select avg(timestampdiff(day, datelaunched, deadlined)) as avg_dur_days
from t;
```